# how to use randn in order to generate random numbers from 0 to 10

Tags: matlab

I'm trying to generate 10 random numbers from 0 to 10 by using randn

I know you can do this by using rand

```
 fix(rand(1,10) .* (ones(1,10)*11)
```

but how can I do this by using randn?

thanks in advance

Comment: Why would you want to do that?

Comment: It's not clear to me what kind of distribution you are looking to create

Answer (score 0):

Not in any sensible manner.

One possibility is:

```
mod(fix(randn(1,10)), 11);
```

but this won't give you a uniform distribution.

You could also use the [probability integral transform](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability_integral_transform) to map one distribution to another.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the cumulative and inverse cumulative distribution functions for the Normal distribution to generate random numbers within a given range.

If you have the Statistics Toolbox you can use:

```
% Generate 10 values from uniform distribution on [0 1]
Y = rand(10,1);

% Find cumulative probabilities of 0 and 10
L = cdf('Normal', [0 10], mu, sigma)

% Generate uniformly distributed values on [L(1), L(2)].
R = L(1) + (L(2)-L(1))*Y;

% Random numbers within the range [0 10] from normal distribution
X = icdf('Normal', R, mu, sigma)
Xint = round(X)
```

If you don't have the toolbox, you can use `erfcinv` and `erfc` instead of `icdf` and `cdf` with some scaling.  See [erfcinv](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/erfcinv.html) documentation for details.